# Error with script saved as single file by Pyinstaller

Tags: python, docker, prophet

I saved python script in single executable file with Pyinstaller, but when I tried to run it in console `./dist/myscript/myscript` it raise **AttributeError** error with log below.

Log info

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "service.py", line 75, in <module>
  File "service.py", line 31, in job
  File "modelInstance.py", line 20, in __init__
  File "prophet/forecaster.py", line 141, in __init__
  File "prophet/forecaster.py", line 154, in _load_stan_backend
AttributeError: 'Prophet' object has no attribute 'stan_backend'
[1413] Failed to execute script 'service' due to unhandled exception!
```

As you see I'm using facebook's Prophet library to forecast time series data and all done in docker the container.

Comment: found same issue discussion here https://github.com/facebook/prophet/issues/1462

Comment: solved by add hook files according previous comment